# WebClient.OpenReadAsync -how to post variables rather than using a query string

Tags: windows-phone-7, post, webclient

I'm using the following code to retrieve a json string from my webserver:

```
var webClient = new WebClient();

webClient.OpenReadCompleted += OnOpenReadCompleted;

webClient.OpenReadAsync(new Uri("https://myurl.com/request.cgi?user=" + user + "&pass=" + pass + "&junk=" + DateTime.Now, UriKind.Absolute));

...

private void OnOpenReadCompleted(object sender, OpenReadCompletedEventArgs e)
{
// response processed here
}
```

I intend to encrypt the variables used but would like to be able to post the variables to the server rather than have them included in the query string.  How would I achieve this?

Thanks - Stu

edit:  Have changed the code to the following:

```
var webClient = new WebClient();

                    webClient.UploadStringCompleted += OnOpenReadCompleted;
                    webClient.Headers["Content-Type"] = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
                    webClient.Encoding = Encoding.UTF8;


                  webClient.UploadStringAsync(new Uri("https://myurl.com/request.cgi"), "POST", "user=" + user + "&pass=" + pass + "&junk=" + DateTime.Now, UriKind.Absolute); 

...

private void OnOpenReadCompleted(object sender, UploadStringCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
    // response processed here
    }
```

as part of the response handling, I check isolatedstorage for a saved file, if it exists then delete it and save the new response into the file.

However, since making the code change above it now won't let me delete the existing file:

```
private void OnOpenReadCompleted(object sender, UploadStringCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(e.Result);
        string myresult = reader.ReadToEnd();
        reader.Close();
        reader.Dispose();
        IsolatedStorageFile store = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication();
                if (store.FileExists("json.txt")) 
                    { 
                       store.DeleteFile("json.txt");   // this errors with System.MethodAccessException was unhandled
        //  Message=Attempt to access the method failed: System.IO.StreamReader..ctor(System.String)
                    }
         ...
     }
```

Don't see why the code change affects this?

edit:

fixed by changing:

```
StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(e.Result);
string myresult = reader.ReadToEnd();
reader.Close();
reader.Dispose();
```

to

```
string myresult = (string)e.Result;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use upload string to post the data: webClient.UploadStringAsync(uri, "POST", body);
You just need to configure the 'body' data how your server wants to see it.

Comment: thanks Jon, changed the code as shown in my question above, but it now throws an error on deleting from isolatedstorage

Comment: You usaually get that exception when you try to access an unsupported method on Windows Phone. There must be something else going on in the event handler.

Comment: Yes before the request to delete the file is the following: `StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(e.Result);
                string myresult = reader.ReadToEnd();
                reader.Close();
                reader.Dispose();`
The DeleteFile worked ok with this code when the inital request was OpenReadAsync, but errors when UploadStringAsync

Comment: fixed the problem, see solution at bottom of my question... OpenReadAsync supplys a stream, whereas UploadStringAsync has the result in a string